# How to inherit Bearer token from Vue app deployed on App Engine?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I have a Vue web app deployed on App Engine. Because its deployed on App Engine, authentication is already provided and requires no configuration on my end.

The web client needs to send a OAuth 2.0 Bearer token along in a request when uploading to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket like this:

```
<script>
axios.post('https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET/o?uploadType=media&name=crawl_request', file,
        {
          headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log('response is: ', response);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('error is: ', err);
        })
</script>
```

I've looked at the documentation from the [google-api-javascript-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/auth.md), but I am not starting an auth flow from scratch.

I've also added the App Engine Service Account as a member of the bucket and provided it with permission to create objects in the bucket

Since the user will need to authenticate with their Google credentials in order to access the home page, how can inherit this Bearer token to send an authorized request to upload the item to a bucket?

Comment: You can't / shouldn't do this in the browser. Anyone could steal your bearer token and abuse all permissions your service account has. Instead, if you want a user to be able to upload something straight to GCS, have a look at signed URLs (which you can generate server-side)

Comment: Would the approach change knowing that this application is for work and only those with our company email can access it?

Comment: An access token is valid for one hour. If the environment is controlled, you could consider creating an access token from a service account, passing that token to the client as a session variable or cookie. You will need to managing refreshing the token for the client. Do not use the App Engine default service account. Create a new service account key and grant that service account access to the desired bucket. Unless you understand security and Google Cloud authorization well, I do not recommend this as there are other more secure methods such as presigned URLs.

Comment: Seeing that the users are already authenticated, presigned URLs look like my best bet. Curious as too when the Google JSON API should be used. Is this just a bad practice to use this at all?

Comment: It really surprises me that an app deployed with App Engine, with integrated OAuth 2.0 sign in does not have a way to allow a web client to upload to a GCS bucket

Comment: It has, signed URLs are that. You can't just hand out credentials to users, it would immediately be abused for crypto mining or similar these days.